# jpql - selecting some elements in one to many collection

Tags: jpa, jpql

In our domain model we have

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "wordlist_seq", sequenceName = "wordlist_seq")
public class QuestionSet {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "wordlist_seq")
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Question> questions;
```

and I wanted to write a query that fetches all `QuestionSet` instances that have at least one question in `questions` collection that matches `IN` predicate, also I would want to only have those questions in `questions` collection that were matched.

Here is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT s FROM QuestionSet s JOIN s.questions q WHERE q IN (SELECT ar.question FROM AppointedRepetition ar WHERE ar.date < :tomorrow)
```

date is of type `DateTime` from joda-time library and I set it like this:

```
query.setParameter("tomorrow", DateTime.now().plusDays(1))
```

Now this works partially, I am only getting those `QuestionSets` that were matched properly, but I am also getting all of the questions, even if, for example only one of them was matched by `IN`.

Are my expectations too high or is there some way to limit the number of instances in `questions` list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. JPA won't return you entities that don't match the reality of the database. If a QuestionSet has 4 questions in the database, the QuestionSet entity will have 4 questions.

If you only want some questions, then select the questions you're interested in, and navigate to their question set.

Or execute the following query, which will return the matched question sets, and the matched questions:

```
 SELECT s, q FROM QuestionSet s JOIN s.questions q WHERE ...
```

Comment: About the query you gave, what kind of object it would return?

Comment: List<Object[]>, where each Object[] would contain a QuestionSet as first element, and a Question as second element.

Comment: Thanks, it may come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Better answer is to update your getter function.

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "wordlist_seq", sequenceName = "wordlist_seq")
public class QuestionSet {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "wordlist_seq")
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Question> questions;

  public List<Question> getQuestions() {
    for(Question q: questions) {
      List<Question> filtered = new ArrayList<Question>();
      if(q.date < DateTime.now().plusDays(1)) filtered.add(q);
    }
    return filtered;
  }
}
```

Now you can call getQuestions function and you will get filter values. You can add filter local variable and use switch case inside getQuestions to determine how filter should work.